# How do I create an XPATH to retrieve the text within span using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Currently, I am trying to take this line of HTML and create an XPATH that can be converted to text and stored as a variable.

```
<span class="a-truncate-cut" aria-hidden="true" style="height: auto;">Champion unisex adult Ameritage Dad Adjustable Cap Headband, Medium Black, One Size US</span>
```

Right now I am using this (By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Champion unisex')]/text()").text()

And I have also used (By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Champion unisex')]")

But it isn't converting the XPATH to text. If anyone could help me better understand what would be the best way to create this XPATH and how to convert it to text within Selenium I would be very grateful.

Comment: /text() wouldn't be used here.

Comment: What would be used then? I am very lost. I tried it without /text() and still couldn't convert the locator to a usable string.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get "*Champion unisex adult Ameritage Dad Adjustable Cap Headband, Medium Black, One Size US*" as a string to store in a variable?
Or are you trying to get the xpath of the element as a varible?

For the first option you just need:
VaribleName = driver.find_element_by_xpath("XPATH_HERE").text

For the second you can just right click the element in the developer window and hover over copy then copy xpath.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did what you said but my variable is empty and my test case is failing. I am not sure why. This is the creation of the variable: hat_verification_links = (By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Champion unisex')]")                and this is where I use it to create a text: hat_verification = context.driver.find_element(*hat_verification_links).text   what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to put driver.find_element_by_xpath when you create the text I think. If that doesn’t work Maybe try “.Text()” as sometimes .text doesn’t work for some reason :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the text and store it in a variable that will wait until it detects the xpath for a maximum of 30 seconds, try this:

```
hat_verification_links = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                ((By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(),"Champion unisex")]')))).text
```

try to print it to check if selenium detects it:

```
print(hat_verification_links)
```

If you meant you want to make xpath as a variable then  get the text:

```
xpath_value = '//span[contains(text(),"Champion unisex")]'
hat_verification_links = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    ((By.XPATH, xpath_value)))).text
print(hat_verification_links)
```

Comment: It is printing nothing. The variable is storing the text for some reason.

Comment: I tried it, and it prints "Champion unisex adult Ameritage Dad Adjustable Cap Headband, Medium Black, One Size US" -- is this what you want to get? Maybe the text you are trying to fetch is inside the iframe. In that case, you need to connect to the iframe first. Or maybe your some of your code contradicts to each other. It ould be better to provide us more details. Thanks